# How to iterate through a dataframe, to create an additional colum?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with account information:

```
Date | Transaction type | Amount
```

I've sorted the data into deposit and withdrawals like:

```
deposit = accountHistory.loc[(accountHistory['Transaction type']=="Cash In")]
withdrawal = accountHistory.loc[(accountHistory['Transaction type']=="Withdrawal")]
```

So, that returns all of the locations of deposits and withdrawals.

The current account balance seems easy to get:

```
sum(deposit["Amount"])-sum(withdrawal["Amount"])
```

Now, I want to graph the account balance over time.

Should I iterate through the dataframe and create a new col called `Account balance` or is there some better way to do it using `pd` functions I'm not aware of?

For each row, account balance should show the `deposit - withdrawal` (to that date).

---

To add some more information:
I have date like:

```
Date | Transaction type | Amount 
X/Y/Z     In                50
X/Y/Z     Interest          1
X/Y/Z     Withdrawal        20
X/Y/Z     Investment        30
```

And I want:

```
Date | Transaction type | Amount | Balance
X/Y/Z     In                50       50
X/Y/Z     Fees              1        49
X/Y/Z     Withdrawal        20       29
X/Y/Z     Investment        10       19
X/Y/Z     In                20       39
X/Y/Z     In                10       49
X/Y/Z     Withdrawal        10       39
```

Is there any other way to do this than using a for loop, iterating over the entire df?

Comment: What would `Account balance` contain for each row?

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) and then create the Balance column as the difference between Cash in (as C) and Withdraw (W). Alternatively, you can use [`assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to make it one line:

Let's suppose this is our dataframe:

```
     Date Transaction type  Amount
0  2021-01-01                C     100
1  2021-01-01                W      80
2  2021-02-02                C     120
3  2021-02-02                W      40
4  2021-02-03                C     200
5  2021-02-03                W     150
```

Using the proposed answer:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='Date',columns='Transaction type',values='Amount',fillna=0)
df['Balance'] = df['C'] - df['W']
```

Outputs:

```
Transaction type    C    W  Balance
Date                               
2021-01-01        100   80       20
2021-02-02        120   40       80
2021-02-03        200  150       50
```

If you want the cummulative value then simply add `.cumsum()`. So:

```
df['Balance'] = (df['C'] - df['W']).cumsum()
```

Comment: This is just returning NaN for me, because 'C' and 'W' are sparsely populated with actual values, mostly it's just NaN and it looks like (int | float) + NaN = NaN. What's the best way to deal with that? I can use df.fillna(0), but that doesn't work that well because now I can't use df.fillna(method="ffill") to propogate "Balance" forward to the NaN values beneath it.

Comment: Use fillna(0) before pivotting, or directly use it in the `pivot_table()` function. See the edit please :)

Comment: Whoops, actually, this doesn't fit what I'm after. This just takes the difference between two cols, without keeping a running total. I think a better method for that, is just to use Boolean indexing?

Comment: Yes, the function is `.cumsum()`

Comment: You should open another question because this answer addresses your original question which is very different from what you have edited right now.

Comment: Yep, .cumsum() worked. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to know it worked, kindly feel free to accept the answer to mark your question as answered and reward us with some score. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that *Transaction type* == "In" is the only case when the
balance increases.
All other transaction types decrease the balance.

So the first step is to check the *Transaction type*.
*"In"* means increase (the value should stay **positive** (as is)),
otherwise it should actually be **negative**.

Then the only step to do is to compute the *cumulative sum*.

So the whole code to compute the new column can be:

```
df['Balance'] = df.Amount.where(df['Transaction type'] == 'In',
   -df.Amount).cumsum()
```